# Using excel sheet as a database with java

Tags: java, database, excel, search, full-text-search

is there a possible way to compare an input from user in java

with several attribute value in excel sheet?

I am trying to read 6 input from the user (Symptoms) and compare it with

each attribute values in my disease symptoms excel sheet.

disease symptoms is something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
disease_id | disease name | symptoms_1     | symptoms_2    | symptoms_3 |..

    1      |  flu         |  fever         |  dry cough    | headache  |
    2      |  diarrhea    |abdominal cramps| abdominal pain| fever     |

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

first, the application will ask:

> do you experience any of these symptoms, then it shows all symptoms_1

values in a drop-down list for user to select from it. then the it asks
for the next symptoms same way.

ex: if I select fever from the first drop-down list(all values of 
symptoms_1), in java I want to increase disease 1 and disease 2 by 20% and

then when I select dry cough in the second drop-down list(all values of 
symptoms_2), so disease_1 will be 40%.

My question is this way is possible in java using excel as a database?

if not please give an idea to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a [JDBC driver for Excel files](https://github.com/panchmp/sqlsheet), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Or use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) directly to read the file.

Comment: @Andreas the JDBC driver uses POI as its underpinnings, and POI is a fantastic piece of kit, but let's politely say it has a certain learning curve :)

Comment: why is a database not an option, you can use an embedded or in-memory db if you want to package as an application, I think it will be more efficient using a db

Comment: guys can you explain in more details. thanks

Comment: @BkrBaroudi Not sure what info you're looking for - do you know how to work with databases in Java, ie JDBC & co? If not go through [a good JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/). Once you understand jdbc it should be clear what you can do with a jdbc driver for excel.

Comment: @fvu thanks for this information, but do you think the way that I explained is possible ?

Comment: Is there any search algorithm is suitable for my case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Take the Excel file as the database, sheets as tables and columns in sheets as columns for your tables.

1 - You need to add the JDBC ODBC driver to your project.

2 - The code below may help you get the source of your drop-down list (user choices). It assumes that you have an Excel File with a sheet1 being your Symptoms table. sheet1 has columns symptoms_1, symptoms_2, ...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:excelDB";
    String username = "yourName";
    String password = "yourPass";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    conn = getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String excelQuery = "select symptoms_1 from [Sheet1$]";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(excelQuery);

    while (rs.next()) {
      //Fill the data for your drop-down list
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what data to be filled in this part ? 
while (rs.next()) {
      //Fill the data for your drop-down list
    }

Comment: Before the while loop, you created a collection or an array that will contain values to be displayed in the drop-down list. In the while loop you fill that collection with values from the ResultSet. Later when you create the drop-down list (ComboBox) you just set that collection as its source.