# Connecting to excel database through connectionstring java

Tags: java, sql, excel

Excel has a built-in option to use a file as a database (view), but how we'd go about connecting and using this is an absolute mystery.

This is the returned connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;
Initial Catalog=Foo_appviews;Data Source=foo.domain.com;
Use  Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=False;Packet Size=2048;
Workstation ID=UID001;Use Encryption for Data=False;
Tag with column collation when possible=False
```

How would we go about using this in our DriverManager.getConnection()?

```
try
    {
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;
        Initial Catalog=Foo_appviews;Data Source=foo.domain.com;
        Packet Size=2048;
        Workstation ID=UID001");

        Statement stment = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "SELECT foo FROM db";

        ResultSet rs = stment.executeQuery(qry);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        System.out.println(err);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you ever search? [Using excel sheet as a database with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539037/using-excel-sheet-as-a-database-with-java)

Comment: Yes, I did search. Seeing as my code is near identical to that link. "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

Comment: it seems you don't have the required driver, make sure you have the corresponding jar in your classpath.